# How to enable health checks on /status when IAM auth is enabled on AWS Neptune

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-neptune, health-check

I have a Neptune cluster on which I am trying to enable IAM auth. This cluster is behind an application load balancer to which a target group is attached which has all the host ips of the cluster. The ips are refreshed using a lambda. There is a health check on /status which the target group checks for health status.

After enabling IAM auth, these health checks are failing with 400 code coz I can't provide auth paramters in the health check conf.

But the load balancer is letting the clients to connect and returns results from the cluster if provided with a proper auth headers from outside world.

My questions are: Are health checks bogus in this case? I have only one instance configured on the cluster, so may be load balancer is forwarding to the only instance even though it is unhealthy.

**More importantly**: Is there a way to enable this health status checks with proper IAM auth so the hosts gets registered as healthy?

Comment: After doing some checking, I don't think it is currently possible to sign the `/status` request from the load balancer.